# Identify Memory Leakage Issue in NodeJS Code

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

I am using swagger-express-mw for my REST API application with express. However I am observing continuous memory increase in my production environment.

My Servers are Linux 4C,16 GB under an Application Load Balancer(ALB). Currently there are 2 servers under the ALB and memory usage has increased from 2% to 6%. I am not sure if GC has been executed on it or not yet.

Below is sample snapshot of memory. Here the app is using approximately 100 MB for process but buffers are increasing. Is it a memory leakage issue?

[image]

Comment: After several hours (at least) under load, does your server process memory stop growing?

Comment: It has been running in production for 4 days with constant load across and the memory usage is increasing. I read on a site that GC invokes itself after usage of 1.5GB RAM. As 1.5 memory has not been used on each machine yet, is it because of this GC has not been invoked yet or it has been invoked and my code has memory leakage. I need help/inputs/guidance on that

Comment: Do you release your database connection after normal request completion? Have you considered using a Promises-oriented or async / await approach to writing your code (it would be much easier to read and verify manually? Does `db.getConnection` use a database connection pool? It may help.

Comment: We release the database connection after every request completion.yes , we use database connection pool. At any point in time , maximum 12 connections are open otherwise generally on an average 4 connections are open.

We want to use Promise based approach but the code was already written by someone and we took the handover in between .

Comment: @O.Jones I have added a snapshot of memory instead of code. Appreciate if you can guide here.